# Asp.net core website intermittently refusing connections

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-express

I have an asp.net core 3.0 website. It has a controller that implements an HttpGet function that does some database stuff then returns a Json object (https://localhost:44356/api/runner/match).

I have a console application that uses an HttpClient to hit that url. I launch the site locally and then I launch my console app. About 50% of the time it works. The other 50% of the time I get:

```
HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

I'm trying to figure out why my console app's connection is being blocked. I don't know how to start debugging this. I tried to implement a retry on the request, but once I get the exception, I keep getting it. So I think it's something non-deterministic happening in my website, potentially related to SSL?

I'm able to hit the url in Chrome locally just fine.

How do I figure out what is blocking the connection from being made?

Is there any chance this is something IIS Express is doing?

Calling code in console app:

```
static async Task<List<Deck>> GetMatchData()
        {

            string baseUrl = "https://localhost:44356/api/runner/match";
         
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                HttpResponseMessage res = null;
                res = await client.GetAsync(baseUrl);
```

Controller function:

```
    [HttpGet("match")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetMatchup()
    {
        int count = db.Decks.Count();

        Random r = new Random();

        int d1 = r.Next(count) + 1; // database ids start at 1 for some reason
        int d2 = r.Next(count - 1) + 1;

        if (d1 == d2)
            d2++;

        List<Deck> result = new List<Deck>();

        result.Add(await db.Decks.FindAsync(d1));
        result.Add(await db.Decks.FindAsync(d2));

        if (result[0] == null || result[1] == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        return Ok(result);
    }
```

Comment: Check the empheral port usage. Requests should not need to be retried.

Comment: How often do you call the code in the console app (i.e. how many requests are you making).  This may be a problem with repeatedly instantiating an HttpClient - prefer to use the client factory instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

Comment: What's your operating system? Windows client (like 10) has concurrent connection limit, which is not in Windows Server.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();   

//specify to use TLS 1.2 as default connection
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

string baseUrl = "https://localhost:44356/api/runner/match";

httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl );
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var getResult = await httpClient.GetAsync(baseUrl);
```